# Switch current "active" element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my web-page. What I'm trying to achieve is: after the user clicks the button, I want the current "active" element to switch to the entire document, rather than the button (I'm sorry if I didn't word it right).
Basically after the user clicks the button, if I hit the spacebar, the button gets pressed (which I mean as active). Instead, I want to de-activate the button once the button has been pressed so that the spacebar is detected on the document element, not the button.

I didn't know what exactly to search up on the internet, and thus I'm asking this question here. My first approach was disabling the button after the click but that would make the button unusable later on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

JS of the button

```
$(".restart").on("click", function(){
    //stop the ongoing timer; start new timer when key pressed again
    clearInterval(stopTime);
    time_limit = 30;
    flag = 1;
    textIndex = 0;
    newTextArray = [];
    correct = 0, wrong = 0, total = 0;
    $('.typingContent').html(typingText);
    $("#timer").text('start typing to start the time');

    
    const { activeElement } = document;
    
    if (activeElement) {
        activeElement.blur();
    }
})
```

Corresponding HTML

```
<%- include ("partials/header") -%>

<h1>Typet - Typing Game!</h1>
<h3 id="timer">start typing to start the timer</h3>
<div class="container">
<div class="timer">
</div>
<p class="typingContent"><%= typingContent %></p>
<button name="restart" value="submit" class="restart">restart</button>
</div>

<%- include ("partials/footer") -%>
```

edit: added relevant code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code that you have worked on to solve the problem be included in your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `blur()` method to remove focus from an element. In this case, you may also use `document.activeElement` in the button's click handler since it will be the active element at the time of clicking. Your code might look like this:

```js
function handleClick() {
  const { activeElement } = document;

  if (activeElement) {
    activeElement.blur();
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleClick()">Test</button>
```

Comment: addEventListener is preferred over HTML inline `on*` handler attributes

Comment: Additionally, I want to make this button function such that when the user hits tab, the button gets focused. Now pressing enter will simulate a click on the button. But if the user presses tab again (after the click simulation), I want the button to be focused again. I have added the relevant piece of code in the question.

Comment: I assume it would have something to do with the tabIndex property